# Proportional width and height with main view in iOS

Tags: ios, constraints, xcode11

To make application compatible with all sizes of devices, At some point we need to give width or height of `UIControl` in proportion with main view that is our `self.view`.

So we used to assign constraint in storyboard, equal height/width to main view and then we set multiplier. Like 0.3 So it will set height of my control (iPhone 5s --> 568 ==> 568*0.3 = 170.4) and so on for all devices.

But right now I am creating app in `Xcode 11.0`. In that I cannot set equal height or width to main view.

> 1. I have tried by selecting my view and right click and drag to superview, but there is no any option.

[image]

> 2. Then I have tried with multiple selection. Select my view and superview and then tried to set constraint from bottom right corner, but no luck.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Until this is fixed in an update (presumably):

- Ctrl-Drag from your UIControl to "Safe Area"
- Select "Equal Widths"
- Select the newly created constraint
- In the Size Inspector pane, change Second Item from `Safe Area.Width` to `Superview.Width`

Although... you are probably better off leaving it at `Safe Area`