# Not able to set proportional height for a UIView in storyboard in Xcode 11

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard, interface-builder, xcode11

When I am trying to set the width of a `UIView` to be proportional to the superview from storyboard the option is not showing up in Xcode 11. But in Xcode 10 it's showing the "Equal Widths" and "Equal Heights" option.

[image: Xcode 11]

Comment: @matt I am trying to make the selected view have equal widths to the superview. While control dragging from the view to the superview Equal widths option is coming in Xcode 10.2

Comment: Hmm, I'm using Xcode 11.2 and when I control-drag from a subview to the main view (or any other view) I do see Equal Widths in the HUD.

Comment: @matt hmm..maybe some issue specific to Xcode 11. They would have resolved it in Xcode 11.2

Comment: That's kind of what I'm thinking too! Give 11.1 or 11.2 a try and see if it's different.

Comment: @subin272 - Until you update Xcode to 11.2 ---  https://stackoverflow.com/a/58467661/6257435

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me in Xcode 11.2:

[image]